# PHP unlink files after read them

Tags: php, file, delete-file, unlink

I read files in a folder.

Now I want to have each file with a "edit", "start" and "delete" button.

The problem is that when I click "delete", PHP will delete the last file read, instead of the file where I click "delete"

I understand that it's the While loop, that does not give any information to the unlink function, but I don't get it right.

Thanks for help! :)

```
<?php 
if ($handle = opendir('rezepte/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            #Entfernt der Datei das ".txt"
            $replacer = str_replace(".txt","",$entry);
            echo "
                <div class='eintrag'>$replacer</div><br>
                <a href='$replacer.txt'>edit</a>
                <a href='$replacer'> start</a>

                <form method='post'>
                    <input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'/>
                </form>";       
        }       
    }
    closedir($handle);
}   

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    echo "
        <div class='warning'>";
    echo $replacer;
    echo "Do you really want to delete?>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='submit' name='really_delete' value='delete it'/>
        </form>

        <form method='post'>
            <input type='submit' name='not_delete' value='cancel'/>
        </form></div>";
}   

if(isset($_POST['really_delete'])) {
    unlink("rezepte/".$replacer.".txt");
}

if(isset($_POST['not_delete'])) {
}
```

?>

Comment: I would also point out a security issue with your code. Consider that a user could submit an HTTP request with any arbitrary value for `$_POST['delete']` and `$_POST['really_delete']`. If the working directory is `/var/www`, a `really_delete` value of `../../some/important/file` would call `unlink` with `/var/www/rezepte/../../some/important/file.txt` i.e. `/var/some/important/file.txt`. You need to sanitize what you read from `delete` and `really_delete`. e.g. If you only expect integer values, fail if they have other characters in it. Also, are you allowing any user to delete any file?

Comment: Oh you're right, tank you. I only write a small php/html/css webapp to call python function on my raspberry pi. So there is just me as a user. Anyway, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to your coding style, you must make coding like following:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $replacer = $_POST['delete'];
    echo "
        <div class='warning'>";
    echo $replacer;
    echo "Do you really want to delete?>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='submit' name='really_delete' value='$replacer'/>
        </form>

        <form method='post'>
            <input type='submit' name='not_delete' value='cancel'/>
        </form></div>";
}   

if(isset($_POST['really_delete'])) {
    $replacer = $_POST['really_delete'];
    unlink("rezepte/".$replacer.".txt");
}

if(isset($_POST['not_delete'])) {
}

if ($handle = opendir('rezepte/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            #Entfernt der Datei das ".txt"
            $replacer = str_replace(".txt","",$entry);
            echo "
                <div class='eintrag'>$replacer</div><br>
                <a href='$replacer.txt'>edit</a>
                <a href='$replacer'> start</a>

                <form method='post'>
                    <input type='submit' name='delete' value='$replacer'/>
                </form>";       
        }       
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring some of the syntax errors in the code above, you could place the file name ($replacer) into the value for the delete submit button like so:

```
<input type='submit' name='delete' value='" . $replacer . "'/>
```

Which would send the value of $replacer right where you appear to want it.

Ideally, though, it would make more sense to put a hidden form field with the name in it like so:

```
'<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="' . $replacer . '"/>'
```

And change your form processor to look for $_POST['filename'] instead.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, but that just change the button name and does not affect the delete sequence. If I press the button now, the last file of the read while loop gets deleted. For example I got 5 files like 1,2,3,4,5 and I press the button on 3, the file "5" get's deleted.

Comment: Please see my edited response (sorry I am on mobile on a train and it's difficult to get these right sometimes)